# get all objects from parse class using php

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm using this PHP code to get objects from class.
I've got 100000 objects.
I want to get all the objects in a single query.

I'm using the following code.

```
    $query = new ParseQuery("news_master");


    $results = $query->find();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove limit to get all data, please try following code :-

```
$query = new ParseQuery("news_master");
$query->equalTo("All",true);
results = $query->find();
```

Comment: this will return only 100 object if we do not define limit.

Comment: can you tell me why you add "ALL"?

Comment: that is field name of table.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2018 and Parse Community PHP SDK and server you can use the each function, which provides a callback and can iterate over all data.  Note this cannot be used in conjunction with skip, sort, limit. See [Docs](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-php-sdk#queries)

An example of a query from their TEST suite would look like this.

```
    $query = new ParseQuery('Object');
    $query->lessThanOrEqualTo('x', $count);
    $values = [];
    $query->each(
        function ($obj) use (&$values) {
            $values[] = $obj->get('x');
        },
        10
    );
    $valuesLength = count($values);
```

the value of 10 is what batch size you want.  If your database table is locked down and requires master key then you can do the following.

```
    $query = new ParseQuery('Object');
    $query->lessThanOrEqualTo('x', $count);
    $values = [];
    $query->each(
        function ($obj) use (&$values) {
            $values[] = $obj->get('x');
        },
        true, 10 // notice the value of true
    );
    $valuesLength = count($values);
```

The reason I'm adding to this old comment is because if you search getting more than 1000 records from parse no good link comes up and this is usually the first one.

Cheers to anyone that stumbles across this!